# Display message from servlet filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters

I have a servlet filter which checks for file names being attached , in my servlet filter i get the file names i validate it , however i am not able to display a message to the user please can someone help me to resolve this .
Thank you :)

Below is the `doFilter()`:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
String name=request.request.getParameter("filename");
if(name.contains(".bat"))
{
    System.out.println("You cannot attach files with .bat extension");
}
chain.doFilter(req, res);
```

Comment: System.out is backend/console output and you have and extra ")" at the end of your prinln that maybe why is not showing on your console

Comment: Sorry for that , it was a typing mistake ... I get the message in console , i want to show it to the user

Comment: Why request.resquest.getParameter()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out` is backend(server-side)'s output stream, if you want to send message to frontend where an end user can see, you need write message into `ServletResponse`, i.e. `res`. For example: `res.getWriter().println("You cannot attach files with .bat extension")`.

Comment: Hey Hui , Thanks , can you provide an example ?

Comment: i get an error ... here is the logs '2013-01-11 19:26:24,078 http-8081-6 ERROR      [500ErrorPage.jsp] Exception caught in 500 page getWriter() has already been called for this response
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response'

Comment: @Mizan Try `res.reset()` before calling `res.getWriter`. This may not be the best way, but I guess you program is just an exercise. Real world's project wouldn't process stream so primitively.